# rvm - default version of ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I did this a few days ago:

```
$ rvm --default use 2.1.5
```

but then when I ran `ruby -v` today I got:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

Is there a better way to permanently set the version of Ruby I use?

==== UPDATE

```
$ rvm use
Using /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
$ which rvm
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin/rvm
$ which ruby
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
```

and output of `rvm info` (note that ruby has reverted back to `2.0.0p481`):

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
$ rvm info

ruby-2.1.5:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin w.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.9 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "8 days 7 hours 2 minutes 42 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p481"
    date:         "2014-05-08"
    platform:     "universal.x86_64-darwin14"
    patchlevel:   "2014-05-08 revision 45883"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    ruby:         "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.apportable/SDK/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/Users/snowcrash/Library/ec2-api-tools-1.3-24159/bin:/Users/snowcrash/bin:/Users/snowcrash/Library/android-sdk-mac_86:/Users/snowcrash/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools:/Users/snowcrash/Library/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin:/Users/snowcrash/bin/gsutil:/usr/local/graphviz-2.14/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Run `rvm info` and append the output to your question.

Comment: is it possible that you just `cd`-ed to a directory containing any of `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` or `Gemfile` files pointing to ruby 2.0.0p481 ?

Comment: @trushkevich no, those files don't exist in the directory I'm currently operating in. And I still get that version of ruby in other directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PATH contains `/usr/bin` multiple times, the first of which is before `/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin`, so the system provided ruby is added first.

You seem to have a lot of entries in there - review your shells initialisation files (.bashrc, .bash_profile etc) and check anything that manipulates $PATH

Comment: How do you know my PATH contains `/usr/bin` multiple times?

Comment: @Snow Crash Because you posted it in your question (part of the rvm info output)

Comment: That's why I asked. I don't see that in the rvm info output.

Comment: Well it's  there - once near the start and once near the end.

Comment: Aah. The <pre> containing the code was bigger than the <div>. There are no scroll bars on the Mac for that area unless you try to scroll so didn't see the `environment` section. Thanks - yes.

Comment: Where's that PATH coming from? `/usr/bin` only appears once in my ~/.bash_profile and there's no mention in my ~/.bashrc or ~/profile.

Comment: Found it. Unbelievable. I've been using the Mac for donkey's years and never realised that it had an `/etc/paths` that added stuff into your PATH automatically.

Comment: I don't see how `/usr/bin` is ahead of `Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:`. e.g. see `PATH` above -  `PATH:         "/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:` then later on in that line: `/usr/bin`

Comment: That entry is where executables from gems are ( eg bundle). The one containing ruby itself is the one I mention in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does stuff like `rvm use`, `which rvm` or `which ruby` say?  That looks like the system Ruby, which to me means you don't have rvm properly installed and you opened a new terminal session and got the system version.

Or, the command was entered wrong.  `rvm use --default 2.1.5`

After that, `rvm list` will show it marked as default.

```
(nick@blerp)-(~)
(507)⚡️ rvm use --default 2.2.0
Using /Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0

(nick@blerp)-(~)
(508)⚡️ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

You could always [reinstall rvm](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) (doesn't hurt to reinstall on top) and make sure the path settings are in your shell dotfiles.

Comment: It is the system version. What's confusing is why --default didn't permanently set the version of Ruby.

Comment: And is it safe to reinstall rvm? Will it cause problems to existing versions of Ruby / gems?